# H5py Driver Issue on Qiskit Nature Drivers

Tags: python-3.x, h5py, qiskit

While using the IBM Quantum experience, whenever I want to install any driver an error with the `h5py` appears.

Specifically, the error is

> "Using default_file_mode other than 'r' is no longer supported. Pass
> the mode to h5py.File() instead."

Does anyone have any solutions to it (not sure which version to revert back to). Thanks!!

Comment: What do you mean by "install any driver"? Is this a driver for the operating system, or in some Python/h5py code? Please post the commands/code you entered when the error occurs.

Comment: Here is the code that I used: from qiskit_nature.drivers.second_quantization import HDF5Driver

Comment: I think the driver is used so I can create a class of molecule and also save it as an H5py file for later use

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add more details about your question. I could not replicate your error based on the information you provided. This is what I did:

First, I installed Qiskit Nature with this command `pip install qiskit[nature]`.
Next, I entered the following Python commands:

```
>>> from qiskit_nature.drivers.second_quantization import HDF5Driver
>>> h5f = HDF5Driver()
>>> h5f
<qiskit_nature.drivers.second_quantization.hdf5d.hdf5driver.HDF5Driver object at 0x7fa28320a820>
>>> h5f.run()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/qiskit_nature/drivers/second_quantization/hdf5d/hdf5driver.py", line 63, in run
    raise LookupError(f"HDF5 file not found: {hdf5_file}")
LookupError: HDF5 file not found: molecule.hdf5
```

There is no error when I imported the `HDF5Driver` module from the `qiskit_nature` package. An error occurs when I enter `h5f.run()`. This is expected, because I don't have a file named `molecule.hdf5` (the default filename). If you have a different filename, modify commands above to use `h5f = HDF5Driver("your_filename")`.

Tests run with Python 3.8.12 and qiskit_nature 0.3.0 running on Ubuntu Linux 5.11.0-1023-gcp.